# How to get a value using Python list comprehension on a list of OrderedDicts

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list called `catalogue` given to me like this:

```
[OrderedDict([(u'catalogue_id', 240)]), OrderedDict([(u'catalogue_id', 240)])]
```

I need to create a new list of `ID`'s from above. This is what I have tried:

```
x = [x.catalogue_id for x in catalogue]
```

But I get the error:

```
'OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'catalogue_id'.
```

I assume this is because it is a list of dicts, how can this be done?

Comment: Use `x = [x['catalogue_id'] for x in catalogue]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[Ordered Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)* are subclasses of dictionaries, as such they behave just like ordinary dictionaries when accessing elements. Use key access `x['catalogue_id']` for every element in `catalogue` to access the values:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

catalogue = [OrderedDict([(u'catalogue_id', 240)]), OrderedDict([(u'catalogue_id', 240)])]

x = [x['catalogue_id'] for x in catalogue]

print(x) # [240, 240]
```

**Note:** You might be confusing it with *[`namedtuples`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)* which support named dot `.` access to their elements.

Answer (score 1):

You access the content of a dictionary with `__getitem__`, not with `__getattribute__`, i.e. you need to use the bracket notation instead of the dot notation.

```
>>> a=[OrderedDict([(u'catalogue_id', 240)]), OrderedDict([(u'catalogue_id', 240)])]
>>> [d['catalogue_id'] for d in a]
[240, 240]
```